# EF retrieves rows with id zero (sometimes) causing new entities to be added to database during update operation

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, repository

I have an API endpoint that updates a sequence for rows associated with an account.

The logic is similar to this

```
public async Task<ServiceResult<IOrderedEnumerable<SomeItem>>> ChangeSequence(
ChangeSequenceRequest request,
CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    IOrderedEnumerable<SomeItem> originalPriorityList = await 
    someItemRepository.Get(request.AccountId, cancellationToken);

    //logic to check whether the lock token is valid

    //new sequence order is updated

    await someItemRepository.SetSequence(newItemSequence, 
    originaItemSequence, 
    request.AccountId, 
    cancellationToken)

    //release the token
    //create service result
}
```

The request contains the following structure:

```
public class ChangeSequenceRequest
{
    public string token {get; set}
    public IEnumerable<SomeItem> newSequence { get; set; } = Enumerable.Empty<SomeItem>();
}
```

Then SomeItem has the following structure

```
public class SomeItem
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public int Sequence {get; set};
}
```

Here's the logic behind `someItemRepository.SetSequence` call

```
public async Task SetSequence(
    IOrderedEnumerable<SomeItem> newSequence,
    IOrderedEnumerable<SomeItem> originalSequence,
    int accountId,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    await _dbContextFactory.DbContext(cancellationToken).Exec(async (dbx, ct) =>
    {
        Dictionary<string, SomeItem> originalSequenceByName = originalSequence.ToDictionary(x => x.Name);

        for(int i = 0; i < newSequence.Count(); i++)
        {
            SomeItem newSomeItem = newSequence.ElementAt(i);
            
            //logic to skip unchanged items

            newSomeItem.Id = originalSequenceByName[newSomeItem.Name].Id;
            dbx.Update(newSomeItem);
        }

        await dbx.SaveChangesAsync();
    });
}
```

### Strange behavior observed

I have set up a console application to call the API endpoint 100s times concurrently with the **same lock key**, but the randomized sequence (still follow a proper arithmetic sequence). Note that the lock key is destroyed every time after a call to the API endpoint. What I have noticed is that sometimes the sequence get's out of whack. I.e. I observe results like this in the database:

What I expect in
SomeItemTable:

```
|      Id             |     Name       |      Sequence    |     AccountId    |
|---------------------|-----------------------------------|------------------|
|          99         |        A       |    1             |         3        |
|          100        |        B       |    2             |         3        |
|          101        |        C       |    3             |         3        |
|          102        |        D       |    4             |         3        |
```

But I observe:

```
|      Id             |     Name       |      Sequence    |     AccountId    |
|---------------------|-----------------------------------|------------------|
|          99         |        A       |    2             |         3        |
|          100        |        B       |    4             |         3        |
|          101        |        C       |    3             |         3        |
|          102        |        D       |    1             |         3        |
|          103        |        D       |    1             |         3        |
```

Or any other variation that ruins the sequence.

**What I currently understand about the problem**
My current understanding indicates that when updating the database context, the entity state gets set to "Added" instead of "Modified". This occurs when you don't give the primary key to the entity. I.e. leave it as 0. You can see that it is being mapped when calling 'SetSequence'. **However**, sometimes when retrieving originalSequence via `someItemRepository.Get(request.AccountId, cancellationToken);` I get some entries in the collection that has id 0. This is the main crux of the problem, and I have no understanding as to why this happens.

**What I expected to happen**
I expect the database to simply have a sequence update of the last call that finished executed on the table as per "[Last in Wins](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/concurrency)"

Comment: Are you writing a client side sequence generator using Count+1?

Comment: No, the sequence is passed as part of the request.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out. The repository for the retrieval of the sequence was decorated with cache interface (which under this configuration uses redis) and the records within the cache would not have been assigned id's, which meant that every time I was retrieving records, some of them would have added state instead of modified due to unassigned id.